# partitions of unity in the proof of the Meyers-Serrin Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, partial-differential-equations

In my previous question, [proof of the Meyers-Serrin Theorem in Evans's "Partial Differential Equations"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1521739/9464), "partitions of unity" is used in the proof (see (2) in the linked post):

> Let $\{V_i\}$ be an open cover for a bounded open subset $U$ of $\Bbb{R}^n$. Then there exist $\zeta_i:U\to[0,1]$ such that 
>   $
> \zeta_i\in C_c^\infty(V_i)
> $
>   and 
>   $
> \sum_{i=1}^\infty\zeta_i(x)=1,\quad x\in U. 
> $  $\tag{**}$

Here are my **questions**:

- If $U$ is unbounded, do we still have $\{\zeta_i\}$ with the desired properties?
- A general definition of partitions of unity (for example in Folland's Real Analysis) requires that for any $x\in U$, there is a neighborhood of $x$ where all but finitely many $\zeta_i$ are identically zero. Do we have this property for the $\zeta_i$'s here?
- What mode of convergence of the infinite sum
  $$
  \sum_{i=1}^\infty\zeta_i(x)=1,\quad x\in U
  $$
  can we expect? Of course we have the pointwise convergence here. Do we have uniform convergence or *[compact convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_convergence)*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good resource for this is the wikipedia pages "partition of unity" and "paracompact space", which I'm quoting in the definition/theorem below.

> **Definition.** A partition of unity on a topological space $U$ is a tuple of continuous functions $(\zeta_\alpha)_{\alpha \in J}$ such that:
>
> 1. $\zeta_\alpha : U \to [0,1]$ for all $\alpha \in J$.
> 2. For each $x \in U$, there is an open neighborhood $O_x$ of $x$ for which $\left. \zeta_\alpha \right|_{O_x} = 0$ for all but finitely many $\alpha \in J$. This property is called **local finiteness**.
> 3. $\sum\limits_{\alpha \in J} \zeta_\alpha(x) = 1$ for all $x \in U$.

Generally, when speaking of partitions of unity, we have an open cover in mind. This is addressed in the following theorem:

> **Theorem.** $U$ is paracompact iff there exists a partition of unity on $U$ which may also be chosen to satisfy *one* of the following "secondary" conditions:
>
> 1. For any open cover $\{V_i\}_{i \in I}$, the partition of unity $(\zeta_\alpha)_{\alpha \in J}$ is **subordinate** to $\{V_i\}_{i \in I}$, which means that $J = I$ and for each $i \in I$, the support of $\zeta_i$ is contained in $V_i$.
> 2. For any open cover $\{V_i\}_{i \in I}$, each $\zeta_\alpha$ has **compact support** which is contained in $V_i$ for some $i \in I$.
>
> If $U$ is compact, then there exists a partition of unity satisfying *both* secondary conditions.

Two other important theorems are

1. Any metrizable space is paracompact. Hence your open subset $U$ of $\mathbb R^n$ is paracompact and admits a partition of unity.
2. If $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$, then we may take the partition of unity functions $\zeta_\alpha$ to be smooth.

Using the above, we answer your questions:

- No.  As stated, you have $\zeta_i \in C_c^\infty(V_i)$, which requires the partition of unity to be subordinate to $\{V_i\}_{i \in I}$ (with the same index set) *and* to have compact supports. This requires both of the "secondary" conditions. But since $U$ is unbounded, it's not compact, and we're not guaranteed the existence of a partition of unity with both secondary conditions. A good counterexample is the one you pointed out, where $U = \mathbb R$ and the open cover consists of a single element $V_1 = \mathbb R$. For our partition of unity to be subordinate to $\{V_1\}$, we're allowed just one function $\zeta_1 : \mathbb R \to [0,1]$, and by 3., it has to be the constant function $\zeta_1 \equiv 1$. But this doesn't satisfy the compact support condition, as $\operatorname{supp} \zeta_1 = \mathbb R$ is not compact.
- Yes. All partitions of unity satisfy 2. of the definition, which is what you've asked about.
- The important thing to realize here is that, because of local finiteness (i.e., 2.), the sum $\sum_{i \in \mathbb N} \zeta_i(x)$ in 3. has only finitely many terms. Although in general the sum may not converge uniformly*, it does converge [locally uniformly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#Definition) because the sum is finite; take $N$ in the definition of locally uniform to be $\max\{ i \in \mathbb N : \left. \zeta_i \right|_{O_x} \neq 0\}$, which exists for a sufficiently small ball $O_x$ about $x$ by local finiteness. Compact convergence follows similarly; if $K$ is compact, the open cover $\bigcup_{x \in K} O_x$, where $O_x$ is the neighborhood of $x$ supplied by local finiteness, reduces to a finite subcover $O_{x_1}, \dots, O_{x_k}$. Corresponding to $O_{x_1}, \dots, O_{x_k}$ are $N_1, \dots, N_k$ as found for locally uniform convergence, and we may take take $N = \max\{N_1, \dots, N_k\}$ in the definition of compact convergence.

*A good counterexample is given by @charlestoncrabb. For the sum $\mathbb R \ni x \mapsto \sum_{i \in \mathbb N} \zeta_i(x)$ to converge uniformly to $1$ on $\mathbb R$, we would need for any $\varepsilon > 0$ some $N_0 \in \mathbb N$ so that $\sup_{x \in \mathbb R} \left( 1 - \sum_{i=1}^N \zeta_i(x) \right) < \varepsilon$ for all $N \geq N_0$. But as we can see in the picture, if we omit *any* of the $\zeta_i$, the difference $1 - \sum_{j \in \mathbb N \backslash \{i\}} \zeta_j(x)$ is $1$ on some interval of length $1$ (which was before covered by $\zeta_i$), and hence not less than $\varepsilon$ for $0 < \varepsilon < 1$.

Comment: For the first question, let $U=\mathbb{R}$. Then $U$ itself is its open cover. What would the $\zeta$ be then?

Comment: I think I see your confusion. The indices $i$ of the open cover $\{V_i\}$ need not agree with the indices of the partition-of-unity (POU) functions $\zeta_j$. In the example you gave, the open cover has just one open set $V_1 = \mathbb R$, but clearly we need more than just one function $\zeta_1$ to form a POU on $U = \mathbb R$. I'll update my answer to reflect this index business. To answer your question directly, *any* POU will work, and trivially $\operatorname{supp}\zeta_j \subseteq V_i$ for some $i$, as the only $V_i$ is $V_1 = \mathbb R$.

Comment: For the second bullet point, do you mean "intersects only finitely many of the $\textrm{supp }\zeta_i$"?

Comment: I'm going to edit (read: re-do) my post later (today, probably). What I've written so far isn't at the heart of the issue here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your update! I'm confused with the second bullet point. I understand that any partition of unity should satisfy the local finiteness property *by definition*. What I'm asking is that  by only assuming (**) in the (edited) post, can we conclude that $\{\zeta_i\}$ does have the locall finiteness property.

Comment: $(**)$ is a theorem: **if** $\{V_i\}$ is an open cover of a bounded open set $U$ of $\mathbb R^n$ **then** there exists $\zeta_i$ with the properties in $(**)$. Theorem $(**)$ doesn't say the POU will have the local finiteness property, so the $\zeta_i$ obtained by $(**)$ may not have the local finiteness property. However, a stronger theorem than $(**)$ holds, and it says that there exists $\zeta_i$ satisfying the properties in $(**)$ *and* the local finiteness property.

Comment: Ah, I see your point now. Do you have an example that  the $\zeta_i$ obtained by (∗∗) may not have the local finiteness property?

Comment: Let me make one more comment to close our discussion. The statement $(**)$ is actually false since $U$ is not compact. But if one *assumes* the conclusion in (**) is true, then the three questions are still meaningful. I have posted a new question regarding the second bullet point: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1782766/9464

Answer (score 3):

In short, the answer is we still have a partition of unity if $U$ is unbounded, and we only get pointwise/compact convergence (uniform convergence cannot happen).

For simplicity why not think about just $\mathbb{R}$ first? There certainly will be a function $\zeta(x)$ with

1. $\zeta\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ with supp$(\zeta)=[-1,1]$,
2. $\zeta$ is even
3. $\zeta(x)=1$ for all $x\in[-1/2,1/2]$, $\zeta(x)>0$ for all $x\in(-1,1)$ and smoothly goes from $1$ to $0$ as $|x|$ goes from $1/2$ to $1$

(basically, imagine a smoothed out bump function that is symmetric across the $y-$axis. It wouldn't be too hard to write an explicit formula for this, but would require a little thought to make it smooth...)

Now we can piece these together so that the transitions overlap in a way that the sum over these intervals is $1$: set $\zeta_k=\zeta(x-\frac{3}{2}k)$.

Here is the picture:

[image]

Now it follows that for the open cover $\{U_k\}$ where $U_k=(-1+\frac{3}{2}k,1+\frac{3}{2}k)$ $\zeta_k\in C^\infty_c(U_k)$ and $\sum_{k}\zeta_k(x)=1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Moreover, all but at most two terms will be locally identically zero at each $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

As far as convergence, why can't uniform convergence happen? if we have a finite partial sum $S_N:=\sum_{k=0}^N\zeta_k$, then spt$(S_N)\subset \bigcup_{k=0}^N U_k$, no? But the full sum achieves the value of $1$ everywhere, so $\|S_N-\sum_k\zeta_k\|_\infty=1$ for all $N$.

The exact same argument, adjusted slightly, will prove that we do have compact convergence. Also this should generalize to $\mathbb{R}^n$, with a little more bookkeeping...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What does "$\zeta$ is even" mean? I'm wondering if the second bullet point is done implicitly in your answer somewhere.

Comment: By even I just mean $\zeta(-x)=\zeta(x)$. It isn't essential, just more illustrative on how you can build these (making the piecing of them together easier/a little more explicit)